# ORA-01830 Error - converting a string to a date object

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp, str-to-date

I need to convert a string to a date object in oracle. Since all this is running inside a shell-script via the sql-loader (sqlldr) I can neither modify nor view the code. The only parameter I can set is the format-string for the conversion process.

The input string does always look the same: **'Mar 11 2015  7:37:53:060PM'**

1. Try: I created a format like this: **'Mon dd YYYY HH:mi:ss:ff3AM'**, but I couldn't run it, because I ran into this error message: ***"kgepop: no error frame to pop to for error 1821" (I assume this is realted to ORA-01821: date format not recognized)*** I assume this is because of the "ss:ff3AM", since I figured out that obviously the **to_date** function is not able to read milliseconds and AM/PM as an input parameter (please correct me if I am wrong, I am not 100% sure about this).
2. Try: I created a format like this: **'Mon dd YYYY HH:mi:ss'** and I hoped he might just cut off the rest of the input string but I ran into the ***ORA-01830 Error ("date format picture ends before converting entire input string")***

Because of this I assumed, that the script does something like this:

```
to_date('MAR 11 2015  7:37:53:060PM','Mon dd YYYY HH:mi:ss');
```

Is there a way to tell the to_date method to cut off the last part of the input string via the format-string?

Every help will be appreciated !

EDIT

I unfortunately cannot use the to_timestamp method since I cannot modify the shell scripts functionality. So I have to use the to_date method :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DATE` datatype doesn't support milliseconds. However, the `TIMESTAMP` datatype supports them just fine. Try `TO_TIMESTAMP` instead of `TO_DATE`?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! Since I have to do all this inside a shell script, that I cannot modify, I unfortunately have to use the to_date function. But I tried the to_timestamp as well in another context with this input string and this works fine, so yes, you're totally right, but unfortunately I cannot solve it like this here.

Comment: If you can't modify the script, then your only alternative is to modify the data in the file, I guess!

Comment: @Boneist, If I am not missing something here, why not just CAST the date as timestamp here? Pardon me if I am missing something, I am on the mobile-version right now :-(

Comment: I'm assuming that when the OP says "cannot modify the script", that also prevents them casting the string as a date or timestamp on the Oracle side. Which only leaves trimming the data in the file before attempting to load it via SQL*Loader, afaiui.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. Saw OP's edited question now. We think alike, I mean, we are on same understanding. +1 from me (as I always upvote your answers, as I mostly find them perfect.)

Comment: This is true, I cannot influence any part of the conversion logic. I am only able to change the input or format string. So thank you for your answers! +1

Comment: Since this answer (and the comments) clarify that there is no solution to solve this problem with the to_date function and since it's the simple truth that to_date won't work with milliseconds, I will mark this as the correct answer, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, sorry we couldn't provide you with a simple answer for your problem. I hope you manage to work out a way to fix the data in the file which isn't too complex/time consuming!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
SELECT to_TIMESTAMP('Mar 11 2015 7:37:53:060PM','Mon dd YYYY HH12:mi:ss:FF3AM') FROM dual;
```

yields

```
11-MAR-15 07.37.53.060000000 PM
```

Then you can truncate the extra empty precision

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! Unfortunately I am forced to use the to_date method in this context, since I cannot modify the code, only the format string.

Comment: Then simple do `SELECT CAST(to_TIMESTAMP('Mar 11 2015 7:37:53:060PM','Mon dd YYYY HH12:mi:ss:FF3AM') AS DATE) FROM dual;`